# Why won't randomization work (MATLAB)?

Tags: image, matlab, random

Okay, this is like the 5th time I have had to ask this question, and still nobody has been able to give me an answer or solution. But here we go again ...

I want to run a very simple little MATLAB program. All it does is RANDOMLY display images from a directory. Here is my code:

```
files = dir(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','semjudge',bpic,'*.png')); 
nFiles = numel(files);
combos = nchoosek(1:nFiles, 2);
index = combos(randperm(size(combos, 1)), :); 
picture1 = files(index(nRep,1)).name;
picture2 = files(index(nRep,2)).name;
image1 = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','semjudge',bpic,picture1);
image2 = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','semjudge',bpic,picture2);
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(image1); 
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(image2);
```

I have tried several different iterations of this, including replacing "nchoosek" with "randsample."

But it doesn't work! Every time I run the program, the script runs the same image files in the same order. Why is it doing this? It's like it randomized the image files the first time I ran it, but now it only runs them in that order, instead of randomizing them every time the script is run.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-18WH6/index.html?product=CO&solution=1-18WH6

Comment: I can't believe that you've asked this question 5 times before, and nobody told you the simple fact that matlab uses the same default random seed every time it starts. So I looked back at your past questions, and you have not asked this question multiple times.

Comment: @woodchips: I have asked this question multiple times, and nobody told me that. Thank you. ypnos: I was out of town this weekend and didn't have access to a computer to come check this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pseudo-random number generator starts off from a specific **seed**. The "random" numbers provided are deterministic. You need to change the seed to change these numbers.

The benefit of this is that even if you use pseudo-randomness in your algorithm, you can always replay a run by using the same seed again.

Reference: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/rng.html

Answer (score 5):

As an elaboration of @ypnos's answer, you probably want to add a line like this:

```
rng('shuffle');
```

To the start of your code. That will seed the random number generator with a value based on the time, and then you should get a different sequence of random numbers.